# Next term in the sequence $1, 3, 33, 55, 565, 6567, 8767, ...$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recreational-mathematics

My friend was asked this question at a job interview (it was nothing math related, so I assume it was more of a "let's see how you think" kind of question, not "how well can you identify series") and, naturally, being the math person he asked me.

That said, I have no idea what this sequence is so I decided to ask you guys. I'm relatively new to this site so I apologize if this is off-topic with the posts that are usually here.

Comment: This question is not about mathematics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The next number in the sequence is $88979$.

I see that the numbers involved are strictly increasing and that they do not differ by more than two, so I suspect this has to do with base $3$ where, in each successive term, the digits are increased by $1$ (the first term being $\{0, 1, 2\}$, then the next term the digits are $\{1, 2, 3\}$, etc.). So I deciphered this "code" to get, in base $3$: $1, 2, 11, 22, 121, 1012, 2101$. In decimal, these are $1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64$ -- powers of two.

So, the next term should be $128$ in base $3$, where $\{0, 1, 2\} \rightarrow \{7, 8, 9\}$ 
This gives an answer of $11202 \rightarrow 88979$.

Comment: And then? $100111\to 988999 $ works by sheer luck that no $2$ is involved!

Comment: And we could always use $A, B,C \dots$ if necessary :)

Comment: Is this something that people commonly see in mathematics, or was that just on the spot intuition? Whatever it was that is awesome man.

Comment: I saw something similar before a while ago where the pattern was the same idea except it was just counting by one in base-$2$, but no, as far as I know this is not some commonly used method in mathematics.